# Nativescript - ERROR Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'NativeScriptRouterModule' was called

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I'm quite stumped on this one and it seems that it's not a common problem. I'm running a building a nativescript angular project where I intend to build a website, iOS and Android from the same code base. I started the project about a year ago and came back to it. First things first, I spent some time bringing all my packages up to date. However, when running `ns debug ios` I come across this error.

```
    ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppRoutingModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'NativeScriptRouterModule' was called.
Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'AppRoutingModule in /Users/user/project/src/app/app-routing.module.tns.ts'
Can't export value NativeScriptRouterModule in /Users/user/project/node_modules/@nativescript/angular/nativescript-angular.d.ts from AppRoutingModule in /Users/user/project/src/app/app-routing.module.tns.ts as it was neither declared nor imported!
Error during template compile of 'AppRoutingModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'NativeScriptRouterModule' was called.
Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'AppRoutingModule in /Users/user/project/src/app/app-routing.module.ts'
Can't export value NativeScriptRouterModule in /Users/user/project/node_modules/@nativescript/angular/nativescript-angular.d.ts from AppRoutingModule in /Users/user/project/src/app/app-routing.module.ts as it was neither declared nor imported!
Error during template compile of 'AppRoutingModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'NativeScriptRouterModule' was called.
Error during template compile of 'AppRoutingModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'NativeScriptRouterModule' was called.
```

It feels like a typescript error I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "web": "ng serve --live-reload false --disableHostCheck true",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "android": "tns run android --bundle",
    "ios": "tns run ios --bundle",
    "mobile": "tns run --bundle",
    "preview": "tns preview --bundle"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/localize": "^10.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~10.1.1",
    "@nativescript/angular": "10.1.0",
    "@nativescript/core": "7.0.2",
    "@proplugins/nativescript-localstorage": "^2.3.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "nativescript-geolocation": "5.1.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "^1.0.6",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1001.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "10.1.0",
    "@nativescript/ios": "7.0.0",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "10.0.2",
    "@nativescript/types": "~7.0.1",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "~3.0.4",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~10.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.17",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^14.10.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "nativescript-dev-sass": "~1.6.0",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.8.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "3.9.7",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.6"
  },
  "main": "main.js"
}
```

AppRoutingModule looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "@nativescript/angular";

import { ErrorComponent, SecureComponent, PublicComponent } from './components';
import { PUBLIC_ROUTES } from './public.routes';
import { SECURE_ROUTES } from './secure.routes';
import { Guard } from './guard';



const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: PublicComponent, children: PUBLIC_ROUTES},
    { path: '', component: SecureComponent, canActivate: [Guard], children: SECURE_ROUTES},
    {
        path: '**',
        component: ErrorComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES)],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And it is imported into my main module like this:

```
...
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module.tns";


@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        NativeScriptModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        PublicComponent,
        SecureComponent,
        ErrorComponent,
        GeneralComponent,
        MainComponent,
        MenuComponent,
        StoreComponent,
        ItemComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        HashPipe
    ],
    providers: [
        AuthService,
        AuthRequestService,
        StoreRequestService,
        OrderRequestService,
        StorageService,
        Guard,
        {
            provide: UniversalStorageService,
            useValue: mobileStorage
        },
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass:  NoopInterceptor,
            multi: true
        }

    ],
    schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My text editor highlight these lines as shown below citing that `Class NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES) is not an Angular Function.`

[image]

This is a bit of a show stopper for me so thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DepickereSven made reference to the changes needed to upgrade angular versions here https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/2238#issuecomment-691459621

Removing the configuration option

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
}
```

will prevent this error.

At this point I should mention that the reason I had disabled Ivy in the first place, was to avoid a different NGCC error that I was getting when trying to compile my application.

After reading this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37508 I discovered what the was indeed causing the error.

In my case, I was trying to compile node dependencies to a higher target version than some of those dependencies would allow. For this error, in tsconfig.json, changing the target version from

```
"compilerOptions": {
     "target": "es2017"
     ...
}
```

to

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5"
    ...
}
```

fixed the error.

Comment: I am using nx mono repo structure where i have a dedicated tsconfig.lib.prod.json for prod mode and in that enableIvy is already false but i am still getting this issue in prod mode.

Answer (score 0):

Change the import to the following:

```
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from '@nativescript/angular';
```

and since you are at root use `forRoot`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES)],
  exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
```

and just FYI: since ns7 just came out your nativescript plugins might not work so keep an eye on them and check if they are updated. Good luck

```
    "nativescript-geolocation": "5.1.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "^1.0.6",
```

Comment: Thanks Eric. Unfortunately, regardless of how targeted my import statement is, I still receive all the same errors. Thanks for the heads up on the dated npm packages.